Adding set-cookie header to response from ASP.NET Identity login endpoint
I'm using ASP.NET Identity as shown in this video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S0RSsHKiD6Y
What I'd like to do is have the response from the /login endpoint include a set-cookie header with the authorization token so the browser sends it with all subsequent requests.
